# Mysql : Join/Relating two tables

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have two table

```
1. Airline -id(primary), name
2. Form - id(primary), operator, other unwanted fields
```

I want to relate Airline.name to Form.operator. Is it possible since Form.operator is not primary key, if yes give me the query.

Can some one also guide me as how will the cakephp model relation be in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $hasOne = array(
    'airline' => array(
        'className' => 'airline',
        'foreignKey' => false,
        'conditions' => array(
            '`form`.`yourfield` = `airline`.`yourfield`'
        )
    )
}
```

This should work. just replace your fields

Answer (score 2):

I would advise you to not use the name Form as is it used elsewhere in the system, however try this (or something similar) and read http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together

In app/models/airline.php:

```
<?php
class Airline extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Airline';

    var $hasOne = array(
        'Form' => array(
        'className' => 'Form',
        'foreignKey' => 'operator')
        );

// other stuff
// ... //
?>
```

In app/models/form.php:

```
<?php
class Form extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Form';

    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Airline' => array(
        'className' => 'Airline',
        'foreignKey' => 'operator')
        )
    ;
// other stuff
// ... //
?>
```

Comment: You misunderstand - here 'operator' is defined as the foreign key in the relationship. Cake knows on which table to find it as a result of the $hasOne or $belongsTo statement and will know to match it to 'id' on the Airline table (unless you have told Cake to use a different field).

Answer (score 1):

in order to make the relations, as Leo suggested, work, you have to follow the cake conventions. In order to save you some headaches later on, I would therefore suggest the nicely written and short material [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/879/Beginning-With-CakePHP) and [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/892/Basic-Principles-of-CakePHP). You will learn e.g. that a good foreign key for which cakephp can do some lifting for you is named `operator_id`, instead of simply `operator` (if operator is not yet a foreign key, it could be that you have a database design issue).
Lifting here refers to automatically recognizing relations once defined in e.g. a $belongsTo.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from `airline`, `form` where `airline.id`=`form.operator`
```

Comment: reverting to pure sql should be considered somehow last ressort as it has various drawbacks like: losing db-independency, introducing security risks.
Kind regards